# What protections are available when reporting problems at nursing homes?

Tags: united-states, health, whistleblower

Betty is a resident at a nursing home, where her bills are paid in part by Medicare/Medicaid. Betty's daughter believes the nursing home is providing substandard care: failing to provide her mother with appropriate amounts of food or water, using excessive physical force to restrain her during procedures, violating sanitation protocols, etc.

Betty's daughter complains to a nurse and files a complaint with state and federal health authorities.

The owner of the nursing home finds out that Betty's daughter has complained to the nurse and the government. She decides to retaliate -- perhaps by reducing the number of people caring for Betty, or by cutting the phone lines to Betty's room, or by evicting Betty altogether.

Assuming the owner's retaliatory acts did not violate any laws, does the retaliation itself violate any laws? Does Betty's daughter have any remedy?